List of decimal numbers to strings in MATLAB
I am trying to create a list of numbers of the form 1.X where X goes from 1 to 65 in order.
1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, ..., 1.62, 1.63, 1.64, 1.65

I have tried the following code but not getting what I need:
v=1.1:0.1:1.65;

I end up with a list from 1.1-1.6 (only 6 numbers). I have played around with the stepping variable, where I changed it from 0.1 to 0.005, still no luck. Once I get the right number list, I would like to convert it to strings.

Id like it to be like this: 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6...1.65.

No I want the list to be 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11..1.65]. Total of 65 numbers. Not just the 7 you indicated.

Yeah, that needed explanation, because that is not how decimal numbers work at all. This is not a list of decimal numbers.

You can achieve that using string concatenation as
result = "1." + string((1:65).');

or more simply, exploiting implicit conversion (thanks to @Wolfie),
result = "1." + (1:65).';

This produces an array of strings. If you prefer a cell array of char vectors, just use cellstr to convert:
result = cellstr("1." + (1:65).');


I think this can be even simpler, you don't need the string() call and can just do "1."+(1:65).' to output the same, as strings handle implied conversion from numbers

You can use num2str() from 1 to 65 and then concat it with 1.:
str_v = cell(65, 1);
for i = 1:65
    str_v{i} = ['1.', num2str(i)];
end

for i = 1:length(str_v)
    disp(str_v{i});
end


Prints
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
1.10
1.11
1.12
1.13
1.14
1.15
1.16
1.17
...
1.63
1.64
1.65


Id like it to be like this: 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6...1.65. Right now this solution is giving me numbers like 1.15,1.25. I dont want those.

I need it to go all the way up to 1.65. So a total of 65 numbers.

What happened to 1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8, 1.9 and 1.10?

Just edited my original post to show what numbers i need.
